# Spore Problem with Missions

Tags: pc, spore

I can't run the "I'd like to colonize a planet" mission. And every time I leave the presence of my homeworld even if its just to my moon, it starts bugging me constantly. Can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it starts bugging me constantly"? It's been a while since I played Spore so I'm not sure what you are referring too.

Comment: An "i" icon appears and disappears a bunch of times and it doesn't stop. It makes a really annoying sound too.